# I'm looking for a web host to put a search java engine. What are the best options?

Tags: java, hosting, search-engine

I wrote a java search engine and I don't have the money to have my own servers. Can someone recommend me a goo java web host?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable administrating your own machine then I would use a VPS like [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/), [Linode](http://www.linode.com) or [prgmr](http://www.prgmr.com).

Answer (score 1):

[Google Appengine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) is relatively cheap. You only pay for the actually used load and network bandwidth on top of the basic monthly fee of (currently) $8.

Alternatives are [eatj.com](http://eatj.com), [jsp-servlet.net](http://www.jsp-servlet.net/) and [javaservlethosting.com](http://www.javaservlethosting.com).